# promise then returns promise

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise

I have a problem. I use a AsyncStorage as a cache in my mobile app. But now I face a problem with Promises. I have a static method which looks like this:

```
static getDiscounts(categoryAndPage) {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem(categoryAndPage).then(discounts => {
        return discounts
    })
}
```

I expecting that return value should be just some json. But it returns another promise.

```
var cachedDiscounts = DiscountsCache.getDiscounts(discountCacheKey);
console.log(cachedDiscounts)
```

This above is a promise which contains my data
[image]

I dont want to call then on this.. How to fix this?

Comment: Your expectations are wrong. Use `then()`

Comment: You can't return the result of an asynchronous function: It does not exist at the time the return happens. Promises do not make  asynchronous functions synchronous.

Comment: But I want to just return this value from this function.Not promise. How to wait for promise to finish inside ```DiscountsCache``` class and then return the value?

Comment: `How to wait for promise to finish` - like this `DiscountsCache.getDiscounts(discountCacheKey).then(cachedDistcounts => console.log(cachedDiscounts))`